# Not able to publish my actions for production release in dialogue flow

Tags: google-app-engine, actions-on-google, production-environment, publishing, google-assistant-sdk

I have completed the overview section and finally was trying to publish my actions but whenever i click create a release button it does not show anything .  I am struck on this. Is this server error or something else?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is difficult to help you without a lot more information. If you update your question with a screen shot of the various pages on the Action Console, along with the details about the steps you've taken and any other information, we may be able to help. The more information you provide, the better our chances are of being able to help.

Comment: are you able to test the action in simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able able to  solve this issue. The problem was causing due to a Ad blocker.